# How to add and use a custom font in my xcode project

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uifont

I am trying to add and use a font within my app. I've followed this post for reference but I can't get it to work.

I've added the font `Frutiger95UltraBlack.ttf` as a supporting file and then added it to my {app-name}-Info.plist.

Then tried to use it in my app delegate to change my `UINavegationBar` but nothing happens.

What am i missing??

```
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                          [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                          [UIFont fontWithName:@"Frutiger95UltraBlack" size:16.0], UITextAttributeFont,nil]];
```

[image]

Comment: `[UIFont fontWithName:...]` requires the *PostScript name* of the font as parameter, that might be different from the file name. Perhaps call that method separately to check if the font is loaded at all.

Comment: @MartinR this solved my problem. Please post it as an answers thanks you

Comment: I'm glad that it helped, answer added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(From my above comment:)*
`[UIFont fontWithName:...]` requires the *PostScript name* of the font as parameter, that might be different from the file name.

Answer (score 0):

> make sure that your font is in your Copy Bundle Resources.

if we not adds font to target then sometimes it happens that your font not automatically adds in Copy Bundle Resources.

> also make sure that your font name is same that you have used. you can
>   make this sure by opening font in fontBook.

if you have different fonts like Regular/Bold/italic,then you have to attach this name to your font name like this-`Frutiger95UltraBlack-Bold`

install your font on mac system.iterate your all fonts programatically , write NSLog for fontName, by this way you can make sure the name of font i.e. PostScriptName.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI, `UITextAttributeTextColor`and `UITextAttributeFont` were deprecated in iOS 7.0.

Instead replace `UITextAttributeTextColor` with `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` and `UITextAttributeFont` with `NSFontAttributeName`